# Nexus Pro is fine with staging repository create but fails with 401 Unauthorized on upload

Tags: maven, nexus, staging

I have a tiny project that I use with the stagin pl

```
[INFO]  * Remote staging into staging profile ID "29ad9cd35d5f3"
[INFO]  * Created staging repository with ID "bizaqutebnd-1010".
[INFO]  * Staging repository at http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/bizaqutebnd-1010
[INFO]  * Uploading locally staged artifacts to profile biz.aQute.bnd
Uploading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/bizaqutebnd-1010/biz/aQute/bnd/test.maven/1.0.1/test.maven-1.0.1.pom.asc
[ERROR] Remote staging finished with a failure: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact biz.aQute.bnd:test.maven:pom.asc:1.0.1 
    from/to local (http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/bizaqutebnd-1010): 
    Failed to transfer file: http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/bizaqutebnd-1010/biz/aQute/bnd/test.maven/1.0.1/test.maven-1.0.1.pom.asc. 
    Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

Since I can create the staging repository it seems inevitable that I have permission. Testing the upload with a curl command:

curl -u admin:admin123 -X PUT -H Content-Type:foo --data @pom.xml http://localhost:8081/nexus/service/local/staging/deployByRepositoryId/bizaqutebnd-1009/biz/aQute/bnd/test.maven/1.0.1/test.maven-1.0.1.pom.asc

Which succeeds without error.

Utterly puzzled ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer it turned out is that Nexus reacts very different when Java is used to do the communications. This problem was fixed by setting the User-Agent header to something else than the Java default.

Likely Nexus has some backward compatibility code for an old Maven version.